# Is there any benefit in fortifying a unit that is inside a city or fortress?

Tags: freeciv

- When a land unit is fortified, it gains a defensive bonus.
- Some land units have a defensive bonus when inside a city or fortress.

Is there any use in fortifying a land unit that is already inside a city or fortress? Would the total defensive bonus be even greater when a land unit is fortified inside a city or fortress?

Comment: On the [wiki](https://freeciv.fandom.com/wiki/Combat#Combat_Mechanics) under combat mechanics, at the end of the section it says: *"Note that fortified units receive no extra bonus in a city: being in a city already gives them a "free fortify bonus."*  - does that seem like an answer? I wasn't sure since just above it mentions something about an automatic fortified bonus.